# Running WebApp within another project as a reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, api, web-applications

I have a webapplication project made in C# and another desktop application using WinForm.
My desktop application include the WebApp as a reference and I would like to find a way to also make the webapplication run when my desktop app is launched.

Any tip on this ?
Thank you ! :)

Comment: if you want this for debug purpose, you can run each on separate visual studio instances right?also is your web application an API/Services project?